# The keyboard of a TextField doesn't show when I tap it in SwiftUI

Tags: keyboard, swiftui, textfield

The keyboard of a TextField doesn't show when I tap it on a physical device and I don't know why, here is my code:

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(colorScheme == .light ? "user" : "userDark")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                Text(localName)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Change name", text: $name)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .zIndex(1)
                    if self.name != "" {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // update name
                        })
                        {
                            Text("Update")
                                .padding()
                        }.padding()
                    }

                }.padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem and found the issue to be ZStack but I still didn't find a solution. Could you solve it in the end?